# Hierarchical regression. Change is not significant but the added predictor and the second model are significant

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm building a hierarchical regression analysis, where I'd like to test that a variable X (continuous) predicts Y (continuous), over and above a model that includes variables Sex (binary), A (binary), B (continuous), C (continuous) and D (continuous). There are 58 observations (I know, it's a small sample for the number of predictor variables).

For this purpose, I built a model (Model 1) that includes Sex, A, B, C and D. In the second model, I added X as an additional predictor. Because a visual inspection of the data indicated that sex and X might have an interaction, which is of interest, I also added sex*X interaction to the second model.

Below is the output from SPSS. It indicates that the second model does not significantly increase the proportion of the variance explained. However, ANOVA shows that the second model becomes significant, while the first model was not. Also, both X and Sex*X interaction are significant.

How would you recommend that I interpret and report these findings?
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.amstat.org/asa/files/pdfs/P-ValueStatement.pdf should be helpful.  It sounds as if you are giving very special status, unjustified, to the alpha of .05.  Not that you are alone in this.

Comment: Thank you @rolando2. Do you think, in this case, I'm allowed to follow up with carrying out this model in different sexes? It does look like there's a strong association of X with Y in males, but not in females. Although, of course, the number of observations per the number of predictor variables are now even smaller, when I look separately in males and females.